# Trying to make getLayout work from next js documentation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, routes, layout

I'm trying to figure out how I'm supposed to implement the `getlayout` from next.js in my application using the new `app` directory instead of `pages`.

My goal is to create a navigation that does not refresh my button state when I change pages with a custom layout that I could control if I want to display or not.

```
async function Profile({ params }: { params: { buyid: string } }) {
  const supabase = createServerComponentClient({ cookies });
  const { data: { session } } = await supabase.auth.getSession();
  const { data: userData, error } = await supabase.auth.getUser()

  const lastLogin = formatDate(userData.user?.last_sign_in_at)
  const userId = userData.user?.id

  return (
    <>
      <main >
      <Profil userId={userId}/>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

Profile.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement)  {
  return <LayoutWithNav>{page}</LayoutWithNav>;
};

export default Profile;
```

I tried to display my component with a custom component layout, but it doesn't work because I don't know where I should put this code from the next.js documentation

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page)
 
  return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)
}
```